# How to define an onLoad function in JSF template that will be defined elsewhere

Tags: java, jsp, jsf, facelets

I'm designing the view for my site, which has a standard login and landing page, and I want to have an onLoad function called for my login page, but not for my other pages (yet). I've got a template.xhtml file, which has this insert:

`<div id="content">
        <ui:insert name="content"/>
    </div>`

Then in login.xhtml I have:

`<ui:define name="content">
    ...
    </ui:define>`

Normally I would put this in login.xhtml:

`<body onload="document.getElementById('login_form:name').focus();">`

But since I'm using JSF's ui composition tags, I can't have the `<body/>` tag in login.xhtml (at least the way I am attempting to do it).

Is there a way to accomplish this with the structure I've described? The way I would think of doing it is to have onLoad call a function in the template, and then each page with ui:define would populate this function. Is that possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I can think of at least two ways:

1. define the header section with `<ui:define name="header">`, and put a javascript function (`function bodyLoaded(){..}`) in it - different on every page, and then reference it via `<body onload="bodyLoaded();">`
2. use facelets params. I.e. `<body onload="#{onLoadJS}"/>` and on each page including the template use `<ui:param name="onLoadJS" value="document.getElementById(..)" />`