# how to prepopulate h:inputText in jsf

Tags: java, javascript, jsf, ip-geolocation

i have two inputtext which i want to prepopulate with geolocation data that is city and country.
This is api i want to use to get location

```
      <script language="JavaScript" src="http://www.geoplugin.net/javascript.gp" type="text/javascript"></script>

  <script language="Javascript"> 
    document.write(geoplugin_city(), geoplugin_countryName()); 
  </script>
```

JSF:

```
<h:inputText id="city" style="width:100%;"  value="#{m.city}"></h:inputText>

<h:inputText id="city" style="width:100%;"  value="#{m.country}"></h:inputText>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First : you gave same id to your `inputText` change the second one to *country*

Try something like this

```
document.getElementById("yourFormId:city").value = geoplugin_city();
document.getElementById("yourFormId:country").value = geoplugin_countryName();
```

Answer (score 0):

So why won't you just create `JavaScript` function which will set the city and the countryName to your IDs (I suppose you will have id city and country, now you have the same id for both `inputText`). And just call it when the page is loaded, there two ways how to do it according this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2375676/how-to-define-an-onload-function-in-jsf-template-that-will-be-defined-elsewhere).